# If I post a form which has an element named "element1" and do not specify a value in a markup, does it post empty string or null?

Tags: php, html, forms, http

an input text element posts an empty string
I am wondering about a form tag which has the name "form1" and no assigned value.
by null I mean "not set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It posts an empty string (if that's relevant to the input type).  You can't post a null because HTTP doesn't have a native representation for the concept.  (You can post, for example, a JSON string that decodes to a null, but that's not the same thing.)

It's possible that what you meant by "posting a null" is posting a set of form key:value pairs that has no key corresponding to the element in question.  That's what happens if you disable the element; if a text input, for example, is not disabled and has no value set, a key:value pair gets posted for it where the value is an empty string.

Comment: so the post value is set and empty, not "not set", right?

Answer (score 1):

It'll be an [empty string](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=null%20string&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string&ei=leizTqaDFoiLswaApty7Aw&usg=AFQjCNFcPSN9c_VP5lNKcgb8J8Xkn2sb7A). . . .

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the particular element type.
You have to ask a question of far better quality to get certain answer.

I see no point in mentioning HTTP headers here though.